# Firebird съедает память

Tags: память, firebird

Firebird полностью съедает память на сервере. Перезагрузка помогает на 20 минут, потом все повторяется. Есть ли способ умерить аппетит Firebird?

Comment: firebird.conf в студию. И статистику со всех баз.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решена изменением параметра FileSystemCacheSize = 0 на FileSystemCacheSize = 30.
Утечки памяти прекратились, все работает стабильно. Спасибо.

Comment: Возможно, таким образом пытались оградить базу от порчи при отключении питания. ИБП у вас есть?

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно поправить аппетиты в firebird.conf. Размер страницы уменьшить, буфер сортировок ужать. SuperServer включить, наконец. Но в целом, это очень ненормальное поведение - птичка ворочает многогигабайтными базами на музейном железе с 512М оперативки. Что-то тут не так.

Comment: На небольшом сервере 8 гигабайт оперативки. Примерно 30-50 клиентских обращений в день. Это точно не нормально?

Comment: Вот тот музейный сервер обслуживает 30-60 одновременных обращений.

Comment: В конфиге FileSystemCacheSize = 0. Попробую поставить 40, к примеру.

Comment: @IvanIvanov А это какая версия базы? После чего началось пожирание памяти?

Comment: Версия 2.5. Пожирание памяти замечено давно. Пришел работать в компанию-проблема уже была. Раньше видимо мирились.

Comment: Конфиг здесь. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28099063/firebird.conf